# How view versions in google docs without writer access?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs

I am having Google Docs file without write permission.

But I can't view versions details.

Is it possible to view versions without writer permission?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to have the `viewer` permission. If you only have `commenter` permission then you can't view version history.